# Mysql default timezone

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

My server is in US, and I'm in istanbul.
Problem is I want to ask mysql about current time. Is there a function to adjust it's time accourding to mine?

```
select * from xyz where dateTimeField<now();
```

dateTimeField will available after 10 hours that it shoud be!

Comment: Probably easiest to set the client connection timezone to match the timezone the server is in: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time-zone-support.html

Comment: thanks  set  time_zone= '+3:00';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use command

```
SET time_zone = timezone;
```

That sets it to your time zone.
Refer to the [details](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time-zone-support.html).