# Php default timezone in sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this php to set the default timezone on my website:

```
<?php date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London'); ?>
```

It works fine if I use `<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>` etc...

But I am running sql queries that say:

```
SELECT * from billing_pdf_archive where datetime < DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 14 DAY)
```

How can u get the correct timezone for this too?

Comment: Yes, the Google query is `mysql default timezone`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql default timezone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019102/mysql-default-timezone) however for a permanent setting you need root rights (I think)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing the connection timezone in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510052/changing-the-connection-timezone-in-mysql)

Comment: I have tried <?php
set time_zone = +00:00;
$sql="select NOW() as now ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
$result=mysql_fetch_array($rs);
echo $result["now"];
?> but I get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING on line 29 (set time_zone...)

Answer (score 1):

Or if you don't have admin access to mysql you can actually pass the php current date to replace the SQL NOW() function.

```
"SELECT * from billing_pdf_archive where datetime < DATE(".date('Y-m-d')." - INTERVAL 14 DAY)"
```